# Class Member Functions and Classes as Friends

Tags: c++

I've written two classes: the function of the first class cannot access to the private member of the second class even though that function is a friend to second class. then I found this example from ***msdn.microsoft.com*** but there is still an **error:** `cannot access private member declared in class B`

here is [code from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahhw8bzz.aspx):

```
class B;
class A {
public:
    int Func1(B& b);

private:
    int Func2(B& b);
};

class B {
private:
    int _b;

    // A::Func1 is a friend function to class B
    // so A::Func1 has access to all members of B
    friend int A::Func1(B&);
};

int A::Func1(B& b) { return b._b; }//the same error as the one below is here
int A::Func2(B& b) { return b._b; }
```

when I write `class A` itself as friend for `B` there is no **error** but I want to have only the function that I want to be a friend for class B not whole `class A`

Is it my compiler fault or this code is wrong?

Comment: You should have no problem if [you do it right](http://ideone.com/XAaIsy). Unless your compiler is broken.

Comment: Are MS$ into fish'n'chips as well ("here is a cod from msdn.microsoft.com") ?! - Anyway avoid friends in C++. Not a good idea as it usually causes more trouble than it is worth

Answer (score 1):

i just added a `declaration` for the `class B`(called *forward declaration* of a `class`) at the top and it compiles. You need to declare the `class B` before you use it as a `parameter` in your `member functions` of `class A`.

Here is the code ->

```
#include<iostream>

class B;

class A {
public:
    int Func1(B& b);

private:
    int Func2(B& b);
};

class B {
private:
    int _b;


    // A::Func1 is a friend function to class B
    // so A::Func1 has access to all members of B
    friend int A::Func1(B&);
};

int A::Func1(B& b) { return b._b; }//the same error as the one below    is here
//int A::Func2(B& b) { return b._b; } 

int main(void){ return 0; }
```

If the error still persists then maybe your compiler is at fault.

Comment: It's called a _forward declaration_.

Comment: Good for you. The OP, or whoever reads your answer, may not know. (Hint: a good suggestion for you to edit your answer!)

Comment: there is still a red line indicating an error `int A::Func1(B& b) { return b._b; }` but it compiles without error                                                              *

Comment: @saeedabbasi Well, use the functions somehow inside main and see, i don't think there will be any error. Also, are you using visual studios?

Comment: ***there is still a red line*** Intellisense can and will have false positives. Meaning things it marks as errors may not be a real compiler error.

Comment: @saeedabbasi yup don't worry about those red lines unless you get some error. Read **@drescherjm's** comment.